# tiinymce dropdown item cashes polymer dialog when clicked

Tags: javascript, tinymce, polymer, paper-dialog

I am using `tinymce wysiwyg html editor` and `polymer`. The editor is shown in a `paper-dialog` popup. When an item in a `tinymce` dropdown menu is clicked, the `dialog` closes and it will not reopen. No errors appear in `console`. How can I catch the click events to stop it from affecting the `polymer dialog`?

I tried adding a `stopPropogation` in the `tinymce` `setup` field but that doesn't seem to help.

```
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.textareaId,
      setup: function (ed) {
            ed.on('click', function(e) {
              console.log("clicked");
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    });
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same problem. It looks like paper-dialog thinks that when you select certain items from TinyMCE drop-down menu, the click happens outside of paper-dialog, so it decides it needs to close.

The quick workaround here would be to set no-cancel-on-outside-click property for dialog (or make it modal). More involved solution would require capturing all click events on TinyMCE element, which I haven't attempted.